# Elasticsearch multiple search terms

Tags: elasticsearch

I've set an elastic index. I have 100,000 documents all with the following fields

```
{
"Make": "NISSAN",
"Model": "FUGA",
"Body Type": "SEDAN",
"Year of Manufacture": 2012,
"Country": "JAPAN",
"Fuel Type": "PETROL"
}
```

I need to create a search based on four possible terms

1. Make
2. Model
3. Year of Manufacture
4. Fuel Type

Below are four possible combinations for a search query

`2012 nissan fuga petrol`
`nissan fuga 2012 petrol`
`petrol 2012 nissan fuga`
`nissan fuga petrol 2012`

Assuming we have correct spelling on the search query, below is how i tried searching based on the search query

```
curl -X GET "localhost:9200/vehicles/_search?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "query": {
    "simple_query_string" : {
        "query": "2012 NISSAN FUGA PETROL",
        "fields": ["Make","Model","Year of Manufacture","Fuel Type"]
    }
  }
}
```

Out of surprise, the search returns an error below

```
    {
    "error": {
        "root_cause": [
            {
                "type": "query_shard_exception",
                "reason": "failed to create query: {\n  \"simple_query_string\" : {\n    \"query\" : \"2012 NISSAN FUGA PETROL\",\n    \"fields\" : [\n      \"Model^1.0\",\n      \"Make^1.0\",\n      \"Year of Manufacture^1.0\",\n      \"Fuel Type^1.0\"\n    ],\n    \"flags\" : -1,\n    \"default_operator\" : \"or\",\n    \"analyze_wildcard\" : false,\n    \"auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query\" : true,\n    \"fuzzy_prefix_length\" : 0,\n    \"fuzzy_max_expansions\" : 50,\n    \"fuzzy_transpositions\" : true,\n    \"boost\" : 1.0\n  }\n}",
                "index_uuid": "3vd2zOgHRIq3BUAJ_EATVQ",
                "index": "vehicles"
            }
        ],
        "type": "search_phase_execution_exception",
        "reason": "all shards failed",
        "phase": "query",
        "grouped": true,
        "failed_shards": [
            {
                "shard": 0,
                "index": "vehicles",
                "node": "Xl_WpfXyTcuAi2uadgB4oA",
                "reason": {
                    "type": "query_shard_exception",
                    "reason": "failed to create query: {\n  \"simple_query_string\" : {\n    \"query\" : \"2012 NISSAN FUGA PETROL\",\n    \"fields\" : [\n      \"Model^1.0\",\n      \"Make^1.0\",\n      \"Year of Manufacture^1.0\",\n      \"Fuel Type^1.0\"\n    ],\n    \"flags\" : -1,\n    \"default_operator\" : \"or\",\n    \"analyze_wildcard\" : false,\n    \"auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query\" : true,\n    \"fuzzy_prefix_length\" : 0,\n    \"fuzzy_max_expansions\" : 50,\n    \"fuzzy_transpositions\" : true,\n    \"boost\" : 1.0\n  }\n}",
                    "index_uuid": "3vd2zOgHRIq3BUAJ_EATVQ",
                    "index": "vehicles",
                    "caused_by": {
                        "type": "number_format_exception",
                        "reason": "For input string: \"NISSAN\""
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "status": 400
}
```

Below is more information on my version of elastic

```
{
"name": "salim-HP-EliteBook-840-G5",
"cluster_name": "elasticsearch",
"cluster_uuid": "mSWKP4G1TSSq9rI3Hc0f6w",
"version": {
    "number": "7.5.1",
    "build_flavor": "default",
    "build_type": "tar",
    "build_hash": "3ae9ac9a93c95bd0cdc054951cf95d88e1e18d96",
    "build_date": "2019-12-16T22:57:37.835892Z",
    "build_snapshot": false,
    "lucene_version": "8.3.0",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version": "6.8.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version": "6.0.0-beta1"
},
"tagline": "You Know, for Search"
```

}

Below is the index mapping for the `vehicles` index

```
    {
    "vehicles": {
        "mappings": {
            "_meta": {
                "created_by": "ml-file-data-visualizer"
            },
            "properties": {
                "Body Type": {
                "type": "keyword"
                },
                "Country": {
                    "type": "keyword"
                },
                "Fuel Type": {
                    "type": "keyword"
                },
                "Make": {
                    "type": "keyword"
                },
                "Model": {
                    "type": "text"
                },
                "Year of Manufacture": {
                    "type": "long"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can i make a successful search based on my search criteria ?

Comment: Hi @salimsaid, I can't reproduce this experiment. Your query returns the expected document. Can you please share your index mapping ?

Comment: @baitmbarek I have edited the question and added my index mapping.

Comment: In your mapping every property name is suffixed with a colon ':' is that intended ?

Comment: @baitmbarek You were right about the extra colon : , i removed the colons and the query now returns `number_format_exception` , i guess elastic search is trying to parse `Year of Manufacture` and finds `NISSAN` instead of a number. How do i get around this one ?

Comment: This error is related to the fact you're using a long typed field (``Year of Manufacture``) with text fields. Are you able / allowed to change your mapping ? You could use a ``multi-field`` definition for ``Year of Manufacture``: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-fields.html

Comment: @baitmbarek i will check out multi-field, thanks for pointing it out. For now i have mapped all fields as text, and i don't get the `number_format_exception` error any more, however when i `"query": "2013 NISSAN FUGA diesel"`, i get all cars manufactured in 2013; even those that aren't NISSANs and i also get all diesels that aren't NISSANs. Is there a way to tell the query to only match specific field values and ignore everything else ? i.e. only match 2013 NISSAN FUGA's

Comment: You should try a multimatch query for this purpose : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204682/discussion-between-baitmbarek-and-salimsaid).

Comment: @salimsaid Do you need to perform AND operation between all values in your text query?

Comment: @AssaelAzran ideally i would like to get only the documents matching the search criteria. I guess that's what you mean when you say AND. As in 2013 Nissan Fuga should only return all Nissan Fugas manufactured in 2013 and nothing less or more.

Comment: @baitmbarek sure! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**

`cross_fields` with `synonym` token filter.

A working example:

**Mappings (Updated)**

```
PUT my_index
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "Make": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "Model": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "Body Type": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "Year of Manufacture": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "long": {
            "type": "long"
          }
        }
      },
      "Country": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "Fuel Type": {
        "type": "text"
      }
    }
  },
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "analysis": {
        "filter": {
          "my_syn_filt": {
            "type": "synonym",
            "synonyms": [
              "nisson,nissen => nissan",
              "foga => fuga"
            ]
          }
        },
        "analyzer": {
          "my_synonyms": {
            "filter": [
              "lowercase",
              "my_syn_filt"
            ],
            "tokenizer": "standard"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Index few documents**

```
PUT my_index/_doc/1
{
  "Make": "NISSAN",
  "Model": "FUGA",
  "Body Type": "SEDAN",
  "Year of Manufacture": 2012,
  "Country": "JAPAN",
  "Fuel Type": "PETROL"
}

PUT my_index/_doc/2
{
  "Make": "NISSAN",
  "Model": "FUGA",
  "Body Type": "SEDAN",
  "Year of Manufacture": 2013,
  "Country": "JAPAN",
  "Fuel Type": "PETROL"
}

PUT my_index/_doc/3
{
  "Make": "FIAT",
  "Model": "FUGA",
  "Body Type": "SEDAN",
  "Year of Manufacture": 2014,
  "Country": "JAPAN",
  "Fuel Type": "PETROL"
}
```

**Search Query (Updated)**

```
GET my_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "query": "NISSON FOGA 2012 PETROL",   ---> nisson and foga
      "fields": ["Make","Model","Year of Manufacture","Fuel Type"],
      "type": "cross_fields",
      "operator": "and",
      "analyzer": "my_synonyms"
    }
  }
}
```

**Results**

```
"hits" : [
  {
    "_index" : "my_index",
    "_type" : "_doc",
    "_id" : "1",
    "_score" : 1.2605431,
    "_source" : {
      "Make" : "NISSAN",
      "Model" : "FUGA",
      "Body Type" : "SEDAN",
      "Year of Manufacture" : 2012,
      "Country" : "JAPAN",
      "Fuel Type" : "PETROL"
    }
  }
]
```

Hope this helps

Comment: This is not so useful as the search query comes from a text field, i have no way of telling the ordering of the incoming phrases. Therefore splitting the query won't cut it in this scenario. Thanks for your input.

Comment: Hi @salimsaid I updated my answer. I hope this is what you want to achieve.

Comment: Yap Yap the `cross_fields` type works like a breeze!! Thanks for that. One more problem though , if the user misses a single letter or misspells either the Make, or Model,  elastic returns an empty result. How can i autocorrect a spelling error and return relevant results ? I've looked at the auto suggester but i can't seem to get it right. I want something like `NISSON FUGA` to correctly resolve to `NISSAN FUGA` and return a relevant result

Comment: @ Assael-Azran I've seen the updated solution, but i have a concern, imagine i want to check against spelling mistakes across the Make,Model and Fuel type fields. On each field i have a possibility of at least 50 possible spelling mismatch , meaning i have i will have a total of 150 synonyms to check against for spelling mistakes on all 3 fields, am sure that will definitely bog down the system performance/search time. I understand that there is an auto suggester in elasticsearch , is there a way to tell the auto suggester to auto correct a spelling error based on the edit distance.

Comment: continuation on above comment:: i.e. use the best scoring suggested word instead of a misspelled query word. Is there a way achieve this in elasticsearch ?

Comment: I’ll have to check and test it. 
If my answer solved one of your questions please feel free to accept it/up vote so other users could use it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204742/discussion-between-salimsaid-and-assael-azran).